# Using Perl VMware::VIRuntime, Virtual Machine created, but getting "toolsNotInstalled" upon power on

Tags: perl, vmware, vsphere

I'm using Perl `VMware::VIRuntime` module to create Virtual Machines.

Virtual Machine can be created, but upon "power on", toolsStatus shows "toolsNotInstalled".

I'm stuck, not knowing what caused this problem

Answer (score 0):

toolsNotInstalled refers to VMWare Tools not being installed. [VMWare Tools](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/340) is a separate software package that you can install *after* your VM has an OS in it. It is optional.